# When does the isomorphism $G\simeq \ker(\phi)\times \operatorname{im}(\phi)$? hold?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Suppose you have a group isomorphism given by the first isomorphism theorem:

$$G/\ker(\phi) \simeq \operatorname{im}(\phi)$$

What can we say about the group $\ker(\phi)\times \operatorname{im}(\phi)$? In particular, when does the following hold:

$$G\simeq \ker(\phi)\times \operatorname{im}(\phi)?$$

I ask this question because i want to prove that $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R}) \simeq SL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}^*_{>0}$, with $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ the group of matrices with positive determinant. I proved that $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup and that $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})/  SL_n(\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}^*_{>0}$, using the surjective homomorphism $\det(M)$. I tried something with semidirect products but I got stuck.

Comment: You need to prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $im(\phi)$ and which intersects trivially with $ker(\phi)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The conclusion does not necessarily follow if $G$ is infinite...

Comment: @user1729 Thank you, I forgot to mention that you also need the group to be generated by these two subgroups.

Comment: (Counter-example: Take the group $\langle a, t; a^t=a^{-1}\rangle$, then this is not a cross-product. Take the map which kills $a$ in the presentation (and so maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$). Then note that $\langle t^2\rangle$ is normal and intersects trivially with the kernel of this map.)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I do not think that even that is enough! My point is that in infinite groups the image can contain an isomorphic copy of itself which can be normal in the whole group without the kernel itself being normal. I do not think generation should be too difficult to get around.

Comment: @user1729 if $G$ is generated by $H$ and $K$ and both of them are normal then $G = HK$ and since they intersect trivially, $G = H\times K$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, right, gotcha!

Comment: Alright, I think i got it. Thank you.

Comment: So if for example i take the diagonal matrices with a real number on the first entry and the rest only ones as my normal subgroup K?

Answer (score 6):

Let $N = ker(\phi)$ and $K = im(\phi)$, then you're asking when, given an exact sequence $1 \to N \to G \to K \to 1$ is trivial.

- First you need the extension to be split, that is, there must exist a morphism $s : K \to G$ such that the composition $\phi \circ s$ is the identity. In this case $G \simeq N \rtimes K$, the semidirect product of $N$ and $K$ : this is the splitting lemma (for non-abelian groups).
- Now you want this semidirect product to be direct; this is true iff $K$ is also normal in $G$, or equivalently that there exists a morphism $G \to N$ which is the identity on $N$.

I don't include proofs here, as they're found in any basic group theory notes.

---

In fact you can get away with the first condition. Indeed, if there exists a map $p : G \to N$ which is the identity on $N$, then a section of $\phi$ automatically exists and the isomorphism $G \cong \operatorname{im}(\phi) \times \operatorname{ker}(\phi) = K \times N$ holds. The required isomorphism is $(\phi, p) : G \to K \times N$ (it's not hard to check that this is in fact an isomorphism).

Comment: Please, does a map $p$ always exist if the group is abelian? I'm trying to prove this but up to no end

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso No, consider $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$.

Comment: Because in this case the only possible homomorphism would be $[0], [2] \mapsto [0]$ and $[1], [3] \mapsto [1]$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso Yes, or the zero homomorphism. Neither satisfy $p \circ s = \mathrm{id}$ where $s : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4$ sends $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Thank you, I will post another question with the exact statement of the example I'm trying to work out. Maybe I'm missing some detail

Answer (score 4):

Even if it can't be applied to your example, I would like to point out that in the abelian case (more generally in any abelian category) it's equivalent to have a split exact sequence: $0 \to \ker(\phi) \to G \to Im(\phi) \to0$

Comment: (The key word being *split*.)

Answer (score 1):

In your special case you actually have a morphism $GL_n ^+ \to SL_n \times \mathbb{R}^+ $ given by

$$ M \mapsto (M/(\det M)^{1/n}, \det M) $$

the inverse being given by $(N, t) \mapsto t^{1/n} N$.

Comment: The map is actually $A \mapsto (A \cdot \det(A)^{-1/n}, \det(A)^{1/n})$.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited accordingly