# For $0 \xrightarrow{f_0} \mathbb{C}^n \xrightarrow{f_1} \mathbb{C}^\ell \xrightarrow{f_2} \mathbb{C}^r \xrightarrow{f_3} 0$, what is $\ell$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

So the question is as follows:

Let $0, \mathbb{{C}}^{n}, \mathbb{{C}}^{\ell}$ and $\mathbb{{C}}^r$ be $\mathbb{{C}}$-vector spaces (where $0$ is the trivial vector space), and let $f_i$, $(i=0,…,3)$, be $\mathbb{{C}}$-linear maps:
$$0 \xrightarrow{f_0} \mathbb{{C}}^{n} \xrightarrow{f_1} \mathbb{{C}}^{\ell}
         \xrightarrow{f_2} \mathbb{{C}}^{r} \xrightarrow{f_3} 0$$
satisfying $\ker f_{i+1} =\operatorname{im} f_i$ for $i=0,1,2$.

Any tips on how to find the value of ${\ell}$?

Comment: Do you know the nullity-rank theorem?

Comment: Yes I do, but I'm struggling to apply it to the question.

Comment: First use your hypotheses to show that $f_1$ is injective and $f_2$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you Ted this really helped me get my head round the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sequence is exact, $f_1$ is injective. So $\dim\operatorname{im}f_1= n$. By exactness at $\mathbb{C}^l$, we know that $\dim\ker f_2=n$. By rank-nullity for $f_2$, we know that $\dim\ker f_2+\dim\operatorname{im}f_2=l$. But since $f_2$ is surjective, $\dim\operatorname{im}f_2= r$. So $l=n+r$.

In other words, every exact sequence in the category of finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces is split exact.

Comment: Your category has only finite-dimensional spaces in it?  Or not?

Comment: I don't think the last line is really relevant here.

Comment: @GEdgar [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence#OfVectorSpaces) claims so too (without any restrictions on the dimension).

Comment: @mrtaurho I'm not sure, but my understanding is that every exact sequence splits even without assuming finite dimensional. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @LAGC You're correct assuming the general case (especially the religious part ;) ). The finite dimensional case follows from rank-nullity, the general using the axiom of choice by picking bases ([Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105081/why-any-short-exact-sequence-of-vector-spaces-may-be-seen-as-a-direct-sum)).

Comment: @mrtaurho Ah I see. Choice bothers me not, but indeed as you say the general remark is not relevant to the proof of the problem that I provided.

Comment: You say "In other words", so you are claiming that **your proof** shows this fact.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I agree, that is not correct of me to say. I will edit to reflect.