# If $G_1, G_2, G_3$ are abelian groups and $0 \to G_1 \to G_2 \to G_3 \to 0$ is exact, then $G_2 \simeq G_1 \oplus G_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

> If $G_1, G_2, G_3$ are abelian groups and $0 \to G_1 \xrightarrow{\varphi_1} G_2 \xrightarrow{\varphi_2} G_3 \to 0$ is exact, then $G_2 \simeq \ker(\varphi_2) \oplus \text{im}(\varphi_2) \simeq G_1 \oplus G_3$

The above is the conclusion of Example 12.2 in *Nonlinear Analysis and Semilinear Elliptic Problems*, by Ambrosetti and Malchiodi.

I worked out as follows:

By exactness, ${0} = \ker(\varphi_1)$, so $G_1 \simeq \text{im}(\varphi_1) = \ker(\varphi_2) \lhd G_2$, so it makes sense to consider $G_2/G_1$. On the other hand, again by exactness, $\text{im}(\varphi_2) = G_3$.  By the First Isomorphism Theorem,
$$
G_2/ \ker(\varphi_2) \simeq G_2/G_1 \simeq G_3.
$$

What one would like to do now is to "multiply both sides by $G_1$ and cancel out in the left-hand side". My question is, **how to do it in a rigorous way?**

I tried to write $G_2/G_1$ explicitly, but it was a dead end. I also tried to follow the hint by Najib Idrissi in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397274/when-does-the-isomorphism-g-simeq-ker-phi-times-im-phi-hold), but failed.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: This doesn't work: $0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{2}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$.

Comment: As  stated, it is false. Counterexample: $0 \to n\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\to 0$ is exact, but your assertion would imply the ideal $n\mathbf Z$ is generated by an idempotent, which is impossible as $\mathbf Z$ is an integral domain. I guess you're for getting a hypothesis.

Comment: The claim is false. See [split exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_exact_sequence).

Comment: Thank you all for the examples. I think that I didn't forget any details, maybe it was a distraction by the authors. The "Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphism" is the First Isomorphism Theorem, isn't it?

Comment: they are closely related, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms

Comment: I am a bit confused by the example of @user10354138. If I understand correctly, 2 is the map that multiply by 2, right? So its image are the even numbers. But when we take this to $\mathbb Z/2$, don't we map everybody to $[0]$? I'm sorry if I'm saying insanities

Comment: The last map sends an integer onto its congruence class modulo $2$, so even numbers indeed map to $[0]$ and odd numbers map to $[1]$. Actually, the decomposition of $G_2$ as  a direct sum is correct if you can prove $G_3$  is a projective abelian group, for instance.

Comment: @Bernard indeed was an insanity, I'm sorry. And thank you!

Comment: minor correction: You have written a $\varphi_3$ in the first line. Is that supposed to be $\varphi_2$?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani yes! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: The usual counterexample with finite groups is $0\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$, where the second map is reduction mod $2$ and the first map send $0, 1\mapsto 0, 2$.

Comment: The authors of that book are just wrong, there is no way around this. I checked the book, that's verbatim what they wrote, and it's simply false.

Comment: @Najib:  I don't have a copy of the book.  Is it possible that the authors only intended *free* abelian groups?  E.g., do they then append a proof of the statement which indicates they are only thinking about free abelian groups?

Comment: @JasonDeVito No, I'm pretty sure it's an oversight on their part. Here is a screenshot of the relevant part: https://imgur.com/AM9nZzb Afterwards, they apply it to e.g. long exact sequences in homology, which can certainly involve non-free groups.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi:  Thanks for the screenshot.  That is incredibly weird because the counterexamples are so well known and easy to construct.  I must say, I'm very curious as to what the "fundamental theorem of the homomorphism" is.  It sounds like the first isomorphism theorem, but it obviously is being misused if so.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I don't understand why the "First Isomorphism Theorem" is a misuse here? we have a surjective homomorphism and its kernel is $G_1$. What is the problem?

Comment: @C.F.G:  The first isomorphism theorem asserts an isomorphism between $G_3$ and $G_2/\phi_1(G_1)$ (which is correct), but does not allow to to conclude that we can "multiply" by $\phi_1(G_1)$ to obtain $G_2\cong G_3\times \phi_1(G_1)\cong G_3\times G_1$.

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso: Thanks for bringing the book name to me, I like its style as Idrissi screenshot shows, but simple mistakes like this post make me hesitant to read it.

Comment: @C.F.G Not very bad, I actually like it and think its worth reading. But they make simple computations a bit messy at times, and some proofs are rather sketchy. If you need references for the subjects the book is about, please send me an email.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: I had seen this fact about "splitting" over and over like [this common false beliefs](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23640/90655) but I never understand why it means really until your last comment about "multiply" end it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

This is unfortunately false. Consider the standard counterexample

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

where $\varphi(x)=2x$ and $\pi(x)=x+2\mathbb{Z}$ is the quotient map. The sequence is exact but clearly $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a direct sum $\mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

For that to hold we need the $0 \to G_1 \xrightarrow{\varphi_1} G_2 \xrightarrow{\varphi_2} G_3 \to 0$ sequence to be a [split exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_exact_sequence) (see also: [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma)). This is for example true whenever $G_3$ is free abelian, i.e. $G_3\simeq \bigoplus\mathbb{Z}$.